# Is there a way to share a single .env file for several Create-React-App apps in a monorepo?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, dotenv, react-scripts

I have a Lerna monorepo with several CRA apps and Node.js services. The CRA apps have common environment variables, so I'd like to be able to create one .env file that they all share.

Unfortunately, my two attempts so far have failed.

1. I thought perhaps I could add `dotenv` to each CRA app and use `dotenv.config({ path: '...' })` at the entry-point of each app. I was surprised that the env vars were all undefined, even though they'd been prefixed with `REACT_APP_`
2. I tried loading the shared .env by piggy-backing the `react-scripts start` command by changing it to `react-scripts start -r dotenv/config dotenv_config_path=/custom/path/to/your/env/vars`. Obviously this didn't work because dotenv isn't being executed by node, but `react-scripts` doesn't have usage docs that I can find, and looking through `node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js` doesn't present an obvious way for passing arguments.

So, I guess my question is: can I share a single .env file among several CRA apps without ejecting and setting the .env path manually for each app? I'd like to avoid this if possible.

Thank you!

--UPDATE--

I found a solution a few minutes after posting (sorry!).

I was able to install dotenv-cli and change the scripts for each CRA app to:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "dotenv -e ../../.env react-scripts start",
  "build": "dotenv -e ../../.env react-scripts build",
  "test": "dotenv -e ../../.env react-scripts test",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject"
}
```

This had the desired effect of sharing a single .env among many CRA apps, though I'm not sure if there is a cleaner/better way.

Answer (score 6):

As an option, you can consider using aliases. Meaning to put your `.env` file into the repository's root and create aliases to each package like so `ln -s [source] [destination]` (this example would work for MacOS, not sure about other OSs).

Comment: This works beautifully, thanks for the bright idea.

Comment: Man I have no words, that is work amazingly, SUPER
Thank you.